# php изменить ключи массива на 0, 1, 2 etc

Tags: php

Привет!
Объясню на примере, что необходимо сделать.
Есть массив

> ```
> Array (
> [0] => val
> [3] => val2
> [4] => val3
> [10] => val4 )
> ```

Надо не меняя порядок следования элементов просто поменять ключи на 0, 1, 2 etc:

> ```
> Array (
> [0] => val
> [1] => val2
> [2] => val3
> [3] => val4 )
> ```

Есть ли в php стандартная функция для такого?

Answer (score 7):

есть функция `array_values`

```
$array = array("size" => "XL", "color" => "gold");
print_r(array_values($array));
```

результат

```
Array
(
    [0] => XL
    [1] => gold
)
```

[Руководство по PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-values.php)